# (MongoDB Encryption at Rest) How do I verify that the encryption is taking place besides checking the log file?

Tags: mongodb, encryption

I had configured the MongoDB data at rest encryption to my replica set using the **Local Key Management** method in as given in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/#local-key-management . I had also verified the following log sentence below in my log file.

> [initandlisten] Encryption key manager initialized with key file: <path to keyfile>

Is that all to it? How do I really verify that the encryption really taken place?

Thank you.

Comment: Start a network monitor like wireshard and check what happens with the packet when you start up.

Comment: Is there other ways other than inspecting the packets?

Comment: I don't know to be honest...

Comment: try to grep some data directly through datafiles in data directory. If getting output then no encryption. 

Means, if mongo is writing data in binary format then ok

Comment: Does it mean if I can open up the file in the /data/dB and see plain text, the encryption is not working?